# How to get multiple files in Fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="file" id="fup" multiple/>
```

```js
alert($("#fup").val());
```

Here I am getting only single file in the `alert()` even though I am selecting multiple files. 
How can I get multiple files in the `alert() with complete url path`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `files` collection of the underlying DOMElement:

```
var files = $('#fup')[0].files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(files[i].name);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mfckx1Lh/)

Also note that you shouldn't use `alert()` for debugging. It coerces the datatypes and is generally not a good idea. The console is always preferable.

Comment: I want complete url path.Thanks

Comment: Assuming you mean the file path on the client, then that is not possible. You cannot get the full file path in modern browsers due to security restrictions.